# Who wrote the Zohar Haddash?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, authorship, zohar

According to orthodox rabbinical authorities, who wrote the Zohar Hadash?

Comment: Are you defining orthodox to mean those who think rashbi wrote the Zohar?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380596/jewish/Rashbi-Works.htm

Comment: Double AA: Not necessarily, the Hatam Sofer thought the Zohar was a forgery and he is definitely a true jew! And I am asking this question about the Zohar Hadash not the Zohar HaKadosh.

Comment: far22 -- tip for you: if you want to make sure that someone sees your response to their comments, write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure that @DoubleAA saw your response to his comment. See [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2067/5323) for more info.

Comment: Seems like a dup. Just can't find of what

Comment: @far22 Just checking. Some people conflate the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same style as the Zohar; there are numerous Rabbis/Sages that give over teachings.

These Rabbis include Rabbi Shimon, Rabbi Yehudah, Rabbi Elazar, Rabbi Yitzhak, and others from the Zohar.

As far as to who actually recorded the teachings, in parshas Haazinu, Rabbi Shimon says: “I am arranging you as follows: Rabbi Abba will write, Rabbi Elazar, my son, will study orally, and the rest of the friends will converse in their hearts” (Zohar, Haazinu).

Therefore, it can be deduced that since the teachings in the Hadash all stem from the same era, that Rabbi Abba recorded those as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Scimonster updated

Comment: Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi wrote the Mishna, but quotes many other Rabbis who wrote nothing. I think the question is looking for who played the role of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi here, not who originated the teachings.

Comment: Yishai is right

Comment: @far22 updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gershon Scholem, the Zohar Chadash was composed by Avraham ben Eliezer Ha-Levi Berukhim (died 1593.)

Comment: Hi J. Where did Gershom Scholem write this?

Comment: Actually, is Gershom Scholem an orthodox rabbinical authority? If not, and I don't think anyone has ever claimed he was, then I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score -1):

As background to answering this question, we need to give a little history of the Zohar. The Zohar was "written" by Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai and his students. Unlike the Mishna and the standard Midrashim, it was not a published work. The Zohar was probably passed only orally to select students. The Mishna and Midrashim most likely were also passed down essentially orally for many centuries, but in a public fashion. Even if the Zohar had been recorded in writing, there were not many copies for many centuries. After the initial spread of the Zohar by Moshe De Leon, many manuscripts were written. These manuscripts did not all have the same content, and many passages were in some copies and not in others.

When the Zohar was first printed, incomplete manuscripts were used. Parts of the Zohar that were in other manuscript editions that were only printed later were called the Zohar Chadash. This is what it says on the [title page](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44740&pgnum=1) of the first printing. The newness is only about when it was printed, not about when the contents were originally written.

Comment: Is this story "according to orthodox rabbinical authorities"? If so, whom?